# What is this type of circular-link visualization called?

Tags: data-visualization

Does this type of chart have a name? More importantly, is there any visualization library I can use to produce it?

[image]
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2007/12/15/us/politics/DEBATE.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [Circos](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/circos/?):

> Circos is a software package for visualizing data and information. It visualizes data in a circular layout — this makes Circos ideal for exploring relationships between objects or positions.

The flowing data blog also had a post on this that you might find interesting:

- [Visual Representation of Tabular Information – How to Fix the Uncommunicative Table](http://flowingdata.com/2009/04/21/visual-representation-of-tabular-information-how-to-fix-the-uncommunicative-table/)

Comment: @grautur I'd like to add this one too: http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/circos/tableviewer/

Comment: @chl:  very handy, I hadn't seen it.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: another funny website: http://www.visualizing.org/

Answer (score 11):

It is called a [Chord diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_diagram_(information_visualization)).

Now that you know its name you can research for the tool that best suits you. I dont think it is nice to advertise tools.

Comment: The only actual answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found that the dependency graph in Flare is also similar to what I want:

http://flare.prefuse.org/apps/dependency_graph

Answer (score 7):

I would just add:

As you point out, Flare has the dependency graph, which Aleks Jakulin [argued was similar but better](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/06/visualizing_tab.html).  This was based originally on the ["Hierarchical Edge Bundles:
Visualization of Adjacency Relations in Hierarchical Data"](http://www.win.tue.nl/~dholten/papers/bundles_infovis.pdf) (Holden 2006).

I personally prefer to use [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) to Flare directly, and you can look at [Mike Bostock's example of the same graphic](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/mbostock/iv/dependency-tree.html).  Here is also an example of [an Arc Diagram in Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/arc.html), which is very similar but laid out linearly.

Comment: Protovis looks to have been replaced with [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/chord.html).

Answer (score 4):

For the #Rstats crowd there are two other options.

`circlize` library ([package](https://github.com/jokergoo/circlize), [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circlize/vignettes/circular_view_of_tables.pdf)):

> This package aims to implement circos layout in R.

[image]

`RCircos` library ([CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCircos/)):

> RCircos package provides a simple and flexible way to generate Circos
>   2D track plot images for genomic data visualization.

Comment: Even more options [on this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599150/chord-diagram-in-r).