# What is a good resource on table design?

Tags: tables

I've seen various theoretical treatments of graphics, such as the [Grammar of Graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387987746). But I have seen nothing equivalent with regards to tables. Over the while I have developed an informal model of good practice in table design. 
However, I'd like to be able to provide a good reference to students.
The [APA Style Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1557987912) has a few tips on table design, but it is only a starting point.

Question:
What is a good resource that provides theoretical and practical advice on the presentation of numeric results in tables?

**UPDATE:** It would be particularly useful to have a good free online resource.

Note: I'm not sure if this should be community wiki. I feel as if there might be a correct answer.

Comment: +1 Great question; will be interested to see the answers.

Comment: @Jeromy, I don't know if Andrew Gelman will be happy with the question, but definitely for small tables this question needs to be addressed. +1

Comment: @suncoolsu I suppose any good resource on table design should talk about the pros and cons of tables versus graphics.

Comment: @Jeromy Just to point to the `apsrtable` R package which offers an alternative display of Tables, compared to `xtable`, and `reporttools` described in the JSS, http://j.mp/97GXWV

Comment: @Peter It will be terribly hard to get better references than those provided by @Rob and @ars. Good luck to all of you!

Comment: Portions of some table design books are free :-); e.g. http://books.google.com/books?id=0sCkxy_1ChMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=related:ISBN1561583464

Comment: @Jeromy, after starting _The Grammar of Graphics_ it also occurred to me also that there should exist a _Grammar of Tables_ (and some kind of `gtable` package). I'm also curious about whether or not someone could extend Hadley Wickham's ggplot2 to feature controls and interactivity from the GoG. I know there are some packages out there that add interactivity, but don't know if they have a consistent grammar.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ed Tufte has a few pages on this in his classic ["The Visual Display of Quantitative Information"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0961392142).

For a much more detailed treatment, there is Jane Miller's [Chicago Guide to Writing about Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226526313). I've never seen anything else like it. It has a whole chapter on "Creating Effective Tables".

Comment: The Jane Miller is book is really quite excellent.

Answer (score 16):

Stephen Few's book [*Show Me the Numbers: Designing Tables and Graphs to Enlighten*](http://www.powells.com/biblio/62-9780970601995-0) has a couple of chapters devoted to tabular display of information.  It's good and recommended, but it's not quite Grammar of Graphics if that's what you're after.

*Update* This sounds interesting, but I haven't read it: [*Handbook of tabular presentation: How to design and edit statistical tables, a style manual and case book*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007DKT4C).  (Curious to hear any comments from someone in the know ..)

Answer (score 13):

If you are interested in table design, I would definitely recommend two papers on the subject by Andrew Gelman:

A necessary preface to the paper on table design is Gelman et al, 2002 [**Let's practice what we preach: Turning Tables Into Graphs**](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/dodhia.pdf)

Gelman argues that graphs are better than tables in the above paper. Then his satire piece provides a look at elements commonly found in tables that make them particularly difficult to interpret. [**Why Tables are Really Much Better than Graphs**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23113375?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) suggest the following (interpreted as satire, these are actually what not to do):

1. lots of numbers
2. don't obsess about clarity
3. exact numbers, minimum of four significant digits
4. default table design provided by your favorite software

Both are great reads.

---

[Gelman, Pasarica, and Dodhia. The American Statistician, 56(2): 121-130](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/dodhia.pdf)

[Gelman, 2011. Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, Vol. 20, No. 1: 3–7.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23113375?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)

Comment: Great, they seem to be both available for free on the web!

Comment: It's not clear from your answer, but "Why Tables are Really Much Better than Graphs" is a satire.

Comment: @hadley I updated my answer to clarify. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: And it has been published...

Answer (score 11):

You might check out the documentation for the LaTeX package [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf); it gives general guidance and implements its design suggestions in LaTeX tables.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this answer is not too off topic, but a couple of days ago I have seen this link on visualizing tables at StackExchange:
[Visual Representation of Tabular Information – How to Fix the Uncommunicative Table](http://flowingdata.com/2009/04/21/visual-representation-of-tabular-information-how-to-fix-the-uncommunicative-table/)

Comment: The use of circular graphics for tabular data with Circos has been evoked here too, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/what-is-this-type-of-circular-link-visualization-called/3159. My opinion is that this is a good way to reduce large symmetric tables, but it is less useful for summary tables with p-values and the like.

Comment: The linked post does provide some good insight into the challenges that readers face when confronted with a table; this can be good information when designing tables or choosing alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

I cover table design in the seminars I offer. My sources are primarily Chapter 8 of Few’s *Show Me the Numbers* and a paper by Martin Koschat:

Koschat, Martin. 2005. “A Case for Simple Tables,” The *American Statistician* 59:1, 31-40.  https://doi.org/10.1198/000313005X21429

Also, Howard Wainer discusses table design in *Visual Revelations*.

Answer (score 5):

The UN Document ["Making Data Meaningful"](https://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/stats/documents/writing/MDM_Part2_English.pdf) provides a nice overview, with rules and examples, of table design in Section 3 (p 12-17).

This is in part 2 of a set of guidelines on 'using text and visualizations to bring statistics to life' https://www.unece.org/stats/documents/writing/

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://stats.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/some-notes-on-making-effective-tables/) CV blog post by @AndyW is a really excellent.  It gathers a number of best practices, useful examples, and a helpful literature review with links to papers and other resources.