# Do's and don'ts when presenting data in tables

Tags: data-visualization, references, reporting, tables

When presenting data under the form of a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(information)), an error can be to omit mentioning the unit of measure, leading to possible misinterpretation.

What are some other possible mistakes to avoid?

Additionally, what are some things to do to improve a table? (while not doing these things won't necessarily generate misinterpretation or other problems).

I'm interested in particular in the case of tables in print or online publications, which may have their specific pitfalls.

I'm also interested in references on the subject, particularly if they rely on usability testing or real-life observations relative to the impact on readers. (But I'd be grateful for answers without references too!).

N.B.: This is not a homework question, I'm interested in identifying possible mistakes I make when presenting tables, and possible sources of improvement. Thanks,

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/what-is-a-good-resource-on-table-design

Comment: @dimitriy thanks, I completely missed that question.

Comment: Please close your question if it is a duplicate or elaborate on what you are looking for that is not the linked question.

Comment: @dimitriy I wasn't sure myself if it was a real duplicate, so I took some time to think about it. I eventually voted to close it, as you suggested. Not sure if there's anything else I can do at this point. // Edit: it seems to be closed now, so everything is OK. Thanks for the reminder.