# Visualizing intersections between online communities

Tags: data-visualization

Let's say you wanted to map the intersections between n different online communities. For example:

- 80% of CrossValidated users also have a Stack Overflow account
- 50% of Hacker News users also have a Reddit account
- etc.

What would be a good way to visualize this? Any examples of existing diagrams?

I've seen [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/visualizing-the-intersections-of-many-sets), which provides an answer. But I'm curious to know if there are other visualization techniques that would specifically lend themselves to comparing the relationships between communities.